# How do I remove a value in process.env?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to remove a value from `process.env`:

```
process.env.VALUE_I_WANT_REMOVED = undefined;
```

But when I do this, `process.env.VALUE_I_WANT_REMOVED` is set to the string `"undefined"`, not to the value `undefined`.

How do I actually remove the value from `process.env`?

Comment: I already know the answer to my question. I am posting the question and my answer to help anyone who may have the same question in the future. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this:

```
delete process.env.VALUE_I_WANT_DELETED;
```

According to [the Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env):

> Assigning a property on `process.env` will implicitly convert the value to a string.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> process.env.test = null;
> console.log(process.env.test);
> // => 'null'
> process.env.test = undefined;
> console.log(process.env.test);
> // => 'undefined'
> ```
>
> Use `delete` to delete a property from `process.env`.