# Nodemon Env Variables Cache

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, nodemon

I'm running into an issue where the environment variable keys being processed by my node app are old and have since been updated. I haven't run into this behavior before, but I'm wondering if a process has cached the original version of the key value pairs and is not reading the new values associated. I am using the `dotenv` module to load and use the env variables in my app and `nodemon` to watch my files. Has anyone run into this issue before?

**app.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
...
```

**.env**

*old*

```
AWS_KEY=AGI....
AWS_SECRET=84HE...
```

*new*

```
AWS_KEY=FJR...
AWS_SECRET=U3F...
```

**console log**

```
console.log(process.env.AWS_KEY); //AGI...
console.log(process.env.AWS_SECRET); //84HE...
```

**nodemon.json**

```
{
  "restartable": "rs",
  "ignore": [
    ".git",
    "node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did u find any solution for this.. ?

Comment: When your nodemon server is running, type in 'rs' into your terminal and hit enter. This will restart your nodemon server, and in return will clear your cache.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer my friend

just run

```
delete process.env.VALUE_I_WANT_DELETED;
```

and restart your application, check the values inside `process.env`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42170366/6344531